# How can I tell if I installed with wubi?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

It sounds odd, but I really can not remember how I installed my ubuntu.

What I am sure is, I had Windows 7 installed on the laptop in the very beginning, then I installed ubuntu so that this is a dual system 1 year ago.

I need to know if the ubuntu was installed with wubi or not, because it determines how I could resize the partition of ubuntu...

Could anyone help? Thank you very much!

Comment: You could also check for Wubi in the installed programs under Windows. It shows up as "Ubuntu".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wubi will show two boot managers. First the Windows one, then GRUB. Plain Ubuntu just GRUB.

Under Ubuntu there is also a `/host` folder, that will link to the drive where you installed the WUBI image.

Comment: The second way--looking for `/host`--is more reliable, since GRUB can be easily reconfigured not to show a boot menu itself (and it's somewhat common to do so).

Answer (score 6):

Unless it's changed since I last tried Wubi,  if you installed via Wubi, if you check 'Programs and Features' in Control Panel in Windows 7 you will see Ubuntu (or Wubi?) listed as a program in the add/remove programs list like all of your other programs.

Answer (score 5):

Boot into Windows>Click on Computer>Now on the drive where you have installed Windows >Do you see any `ubuntu` folders?

If you don't, then you didn't installed Ubuntu via Wubi

If you do, then you did installed Ubuntu via Wubi.

Answer (score 5):

#### From Windows

You should have a `C:\ubuntu\disks` folder and into this a file `root.disk`.
The drive is not necessarily the `C:`, look for it in every volume known to Windows.

#### From Ubuntu

The command `mount | grep ^/dev` should return an output similar to

```
/dev/loop0 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
/dev/sda2 on /host type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

In particular a loop device mounted on the root partition (the `/`), and a real partition mounted on `/host`.

Answer (score 4):

if you only have ntfs or fat32 partitions and no Linux partitions like etx2, ext3 or ext4 then you have installed with Wubi. Windows would report Linux partitions like "Unrecognized partition" or similar so if you don't have any of those, Wubi was used.

Comment: Windows doesn't see anything?... they won't show on COmputer nor the windows resize assitant.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Windows Control Panel. Search for “Wubi”. If it’s there, then you have used Wubi.

Alternatively, check for Wubi in the list of installed programs. It shows up as “Ubuntu”:

[image: Screenshot of Windows “Programs and Features” dialog showing where to find Ubuntu.]

Answer (score 0):

you open wubi. if it says to uninstall, you used wubi.